# Google Map is openning automatically on iOS only

Tags: ios, wordpress

i have a site that has a google map on it`s homepage,
and when you enter the site the Google Map is openning automatically on iOS only.
Android just fine.
How do i block or change that feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to open site google maps only just enter this code. Hopefully it's helpful and answering your questions

```
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
        // this if you have the apps, you can open google maps here. if you don't want just fill this to open google maps via safari then.         
            } else {
                //cannot use google maps
            }
        }
```